# WebView redirects to ads

Tags: android, redirect, webview

I have a webview.I have enabled the javascript in webview settings.It is working nicely most of the time,But when I load some urls like "http://www.songspk.onl/" in it, it first opens the original link then redirects to another page mostly to some advertisement.I need to stop my webview to open such advertisement.

Comment: you can't because songs.pk itself is loading the advertisement and you cannot handle it from your side

Comment: thanks for the such a quick answer